# How do I add liking and commenting to ActiveStorage blobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

The title says it all. How can I define relationships on `ActiveStorage::Attachment`'s which are associated with my model? I want to be able to `comment` and `react` to the `photos` as well as the `Post`.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :reactions, as: :reactionable

  has_many_attached :uploads
end
```

Answer (score 3):

At the very least you can do this by introducing an intermediary model (which will be the target of likes/reactions and will host the upload)

```
class Post
  has_many :likable_photos
end

class LikablePhoto
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable # or however else you decide to store likes
  has_many :reactions, as: :reactionable    

  has_one_attached :upload
end
```